# Error on Multiple Array Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, visual-c++

please advise why below do not work. use `VC2017`:

```
long **l;
l = new long [5][7];
```

it shows error as:

> "a value of type "long*[7]" can not be assigned an entity of
>   long**"...

How can I solve it?

Comment: long **l=NULL;
l=new long [5][7];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare and init the first array of pointer to `long*` and then assign to each his own array as:

```
long** l = new long*[5]; // declare array of pointer of 5 cell
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    l[i] = new long[7]; // assign to each cell array with 7 cells
```

Remember that anything allocated with new is created on the heap and must be de-allocated with delete.